# one-to many найти сумму всех дочерних элементов

Tags: sql, hibernate

Всем привет.
Имеется иерархия сущностей `Entity: main,-> sub,-> subSub` с связью `one-to-many` и полем `summa`. Требуется найти общую сумму родителя main и всех **его** дочерних элементов `sub` и `subSub`.Дочерних элементов может быть много.Можна ли это оформить в JPQL/SQL запрос?
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
@Entity
public class MainCompany {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private int summa;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "mainCompany",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<<SubCompanies>> subCompaniesList;

@Entity
public class SubCompanies {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private int summa;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MainCompany mainCompany;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "subCompanies" ,fetch =   FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<<SubSubCompanies>>subSubCompanies;

@Entity
public class SubSubCompanies {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private int summa;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SubCompanies subCompanies;
```

Comment: Приведите структуру таблиц, желательно с тестовыми данными и результат который вы хотите получить

Comment: Какое отношение "иерархия сущностей Entity" имеет к SQL? Если у вас вопрос по какой либо ORM укажите ее, если нужно решение на SQL укажите структуру таблиц.